# how to get data of trackers controller which is assigned to a user?

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

Hi I`m building a tracking website to track some data .

Now Im building a page so i can see users data at admin panel.

I already built it and its working perfect but i got some problems and i want to improve my coding skills .

Heres my Controller

```
    <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;
use App\Models\Tracker;
use App\Models\User;

class HomeController
{
    public function index()
    {


        $Adminadd = Tracker::whereHas('name', function($q) 
        {
            $name = 'Admin';
            $q->where('name', '=', $name);
        })->sum('add_slp');
        
        $Admindelete = Tracker::whereHas('name', function($q) 
        {
            $name = 'Admin';
            $q->where('name', '=', $name);
        })->sum('delete_slp');
    
        $Admin = $Adminadd-$Admindelete;

        $Raphaeladd = Tracker::whereHas('name', function($q) 
        {
            $name = 'Raphael';
            $q->where('name', '=', $name);
        })->sum('add_slp');
        
        $Raphaeldelete = Tracker::whereHas('name', function($q) 
        {
            $name = 'Raphael';
            $q->where('name', '=', $name);
        })->sum('delete_slp');
    
        $Raphael = $Raphaeladd-$Raphaeldelete;
        
        $Jaynardadd = Tracker::whereHas('name', function($q) 
        {
            $name = 'Jaynard';
            $q->where('name', '=', $name);
        })->sum('add_slp');
        
        $Jaynarddelete = Tracker::whereHas('name', function($q) 
        {
            $name = 'Jaynard';
            $q->where('name', '=', $name);
        })->sum('delete_slp');
    
        $Jaynard = $Jaynardadd-$Jaynarddelete;

        $Glenadd = Tracker::whereHas('name', function($q) 
        {
            $name = 'Glen';
            $q->where('name', '=', $name);
        })->sum('add_slp');
        
        $Glendelete = Tracker::whereHas('name', function($q) 
        {
            $name = 'Glen';
            $q->where('name', '=', $name);
        })->sum('delete_slp');
    
        $Glen = $Glenadd-$Glendelete;

        $Nickieadd = Tracker::whereHas('name', function($q) 
        {
            $name = 'Nickie';
            $q->where('name', '=', $name);
        })->sum('add_slp');
        
        $Nickiedelete = Tracker::whereHas('name', function($q) 
        {
            $name = 'Nickie';
            $q->where('name', '=', $name);
        })->sum('delete_slp');
    
        $Nickie = $Nickieadd-$Nickiedelete;

        $Joshuaadd = Tracker::whereHas('name', function($q) 
        {
            $name = 'Joshua';
            $q->where('name', '=', $name);
        })->sum('add_slp');
        
        $Joshuadelete = Tracker::whereHas('name', function($q) 
        {
            $name = 'Joshua';
            $q->where('name', '=', $name);
        })->sum('delete_slp');
    
        $Joshua = $Joshuaadd-$Joshuadelete;

        $Harvieadd = Tracker::whereHas('name', function($q) 
        {
            $name = 'Harvie';
            $q->where('name', '=', $name);
        })->sum('add_slp');
        
        $Harviedelete = Tracker::whereHas('name', function($q) 
        {
            $name = 'Harvie';
            $q->where('name', '=', $name);
        })->sum('delete_slp');
    
        $Harvie = $Harvieadd-$Harviedelete;

        $Arieladd = Tracker::whereHas('name', function($q) 
        {
            $name = 'Ariel';
            $q->where('name', '=', $name);
        })->sum('add_slp');
        
        $Arieldelete = Tracker::whereHas('name', function($q) 
        {
            $name = 'Ariel';
            $q->where('name', '=', $name);
        })->sum('delete_slp');
    
        $Ariel = $Arieladd-$Arieldelete;

        $Emmanadd = Tracker::whereHas('name', function($q) 
        {
            $name = 'Emman';
            $q->where('name', '=', $name);
        })->sum('add_slp');
        
        $Emmandelete = Tracker::whereHas('name', function($q) 
        {
            $name = 'Emman';
            $q->where('name', '=', $name);
        })->sum('delete_slp');
    
        $Emman = $Emmanadd-$Emmandelete;

        $Clarenceadd = Tracker::whereHas('name', function($q) 
        {
            $name = 'Clarence';
            $q->where('name', '=', $name);
        })->sum('add_slp');
        
        $Clarencedelete = Tracker::whereHas('name', function($q) 
        {
            $name = 'Clarence';
            $q->where('name', '=', $name);
        })->sum('delete_slp');
    
        $Clarence = $Clarenceadd-$Clarencedelete;

        $Jamesadd = Tracker::whereHas('name', function($q) 
        {
            $name = 'James';
            $q->where('name', '=', $name);
        })->sum('add_slp');
        
        $Jamesdelete = Tracker::whereHas('name', function($q) 
        {
            $name = 'James';
            $q->where('name', '=', $name);
        })->sum('delete_slp');
    
        $James = $Jamesadd-$Jamesdelete;

        $Tinaadd = Tracker::whereHas('name', function($q) 
        {
            $name = 'Tina';
            $q->where('name', '=', $name);
        })->sum('add_slp');
        
        $Tinadelete = Tracker::whereHas('name', function($q) 
        {
            $name = 'Tina';
            $q->where('name', '=', $name);
        })->sum('delete_slp');
    
        $Tina = $Tinaadd-$Tinadelete;
        
        return view('home',compact('Admin','Raphael','Glen','Nickie','Joshua','Jaynard','Harvie','Ariel','Emman','Clarence','James','Tina'));
    }
}
```

and heres my View

```
@extends('layouts.admin')
@section('content')
<div class="content">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">
                    Dashboard
                </div>

                    
                <div class="card-body">
                    @if(session('status'))
                        <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
                            {{ session('status') }}
                        </div>
                    @endif
                    <table class="table">
                        <tr>
                            <th scope="col">#</th>
                            <th scope="col">Name</th>
                            <th scope="col">Total SLP</th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th scope="row">1</th>
                            <td>Raphael</td>
                            <td>{{$Raphael}}</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th scope="row">2</th>
                            <td>Jaynard</td>
                            <td>{{$Jaynard}}</td>
                          </tr>
                          <tr>
                            <th scope="row">3</th>
                            <td>Glen</td>
                            <td>{{$Glen}}</td>
                          </tr>
                          <tr>
                            <th scope="row">4</th>
                            <td>Nickie</td>
                            <td>{{$Nickie}}</td>
                          </tr>
                          <tr>
                            <th scope="row">5</th>
                            <td>Joshua</td>
                            <td>{{$Joshua}}</td>
                          </tr>
                          <tr>
                            <th scope="row">6</th>
                            <td>Harvie</td>
                            <td>{{$Harvie}}</td>
                          </tr>
                          <tr>
                            <th scope="row">7</th>
                            <td>Ariel</td>
                            <td>{{$Ariel}}</td>
                          </tr>
                          <tr>
                            <th scope="row">8</th>
                            <td>Emman</td>
                            <td>{{$Emman}}</td>
                          </tr>
                          <tr>
                            <th scope="row">9</th>
                            <td>Clarence</td>
                            <td>{{$Clarence}}</td>
                          </tr>
                          <tr>
                            <th scope="row">10</th>
                            <td>James</td>
                            <td>{{$James}}</td>
                          </tr>
                          <tr>
                            <th scope="row">11</th>
                            <td>Tina</td>
                            <td>{{$Tina}}</td>
                          </tr>
                      </table>

                                    </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
@section('scripts')
@parent

@endsection
```

My Users Controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Http\Requests\MassDestroyUserRequest;
use App\Http\Requests\StoreUserRequest;
use App\Http\Requests\UpdateUserRequest;
use App\Models\Role;
use App\Models\User;
use Gate;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class UsersController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        abort_if(Gate::denies('user_access'), Response::HTTP_FORBIDDEN, '403 Forbidden');

        $users = User::with(['roles'])->get();

        return view('admin.users.index', compact('users'));
    }

    public function create()
    {
        abort_if(Gate::denies('user_create'), Response::HTTP_FORBIDDEN, '403 Forbidden');

        $roles = Role::pluck('title', 'id');

        return view('admin.users.create', compact('roles'));
    }

    public function store(StoreUserRequest $request)
    {
        $user = User::create($request->all());
        $user->roles()->sync($request->input('roles', []));

        return redirect()->route('admin.users.index');
    }

    public function edit(User $user)
    {
        abort_if(Gate::denies('user_edit'), Response::HTTP_FORBIDDEN, '403 Forbidden');

        $roles = Role::pluck('title', 'id');

        $user->load('roles');

        return view('admin.users.edit', compact('roles', 'user'));
    }

    public function update(UpdateUserRequest $request, User $user)
    {
        $user->update($request->all());
        $user->roles()->sync($request->input('roles', []));

        return redirect()->route('admin.users.index');
    }

    public function show(User $user)
    {
        abort_if(Gate::denies('user_show'), Response::HTTP_FORBIDDEN, '403 Forbidden');

        $user->load('roles');

        return view('admin.users.show', compact('user'));
    }

    public function destroy(User $user)
    {
        abort_if(Gate::denies('user_delete'), Response::HTTP_FORBIDDEN, '403 Forbidden');

        $user->delete();

        return back();
    }

    public function massDestroy(MassDestroyUserRequest $request)
    {
        User::whereIn('id', request('ids'))->delete();

        return response(null, Response::HTTP_NO_CONTENT);
    }
}
```

My TrackerController

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Http\Requests\MassDestroyTrackerRequest;
use App\Http\Requests\StoreTrackerRequest;
use App\Http\Requests\UpdateTrackerRequest;
use App\Models\Tracker;
use App\Models\User;
use Gate;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class TrackerController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        abort_if(Gate::denies('tracker_access'), Response::HTTP_FORBIDDEN, '403 Forbidden');

        $trackers = Tracker::with(['name'])->get();

        return view('admin.trackers.index', compact('trackers'));
    }

    public function create()
    {
        abort_if(Gate::denies('tracker_create'), Response::HTTP_FORBIDDEN, '403 Forbidden');

        $names = User::pluck('name', 'id')->prepend(trans('global.pleaseSelect'), '');

        return view('admin.trackers.create', compact('names'));
    }

    public function store(StoreTrackerRequest $request)
    {
        $tracker = Tracker::create($request->all());

        return redirect()->route('admin.trackers.index');
    }

    public function edit(Tracker $tracker)
    {
        abort_if(Gate::denies('tracker_edit'), Response::HTTP_FORBIDDEN, '403 Forbidden');

        $names = User::pluck('name', 'id')->prepend(trans('global.pleaseSelect'), '');

        $tracker->load('name');

        return view('admin.trackers.edit', compact('names', 'tracker'));
    }

    public function update(UpdateTrackerRequest $request, Tracker $tracker)
    {
        $tracker->update($request->all());

        return redirect()->route('admin.trackers.index');
    }

    public function show(Tracker $tracker)
    {
        abort_if(Gate::denies('tracker_show'), Response::HTTP_FORBIDDEN, '403 Forbidden');

        $tracker->load('name');

        return view('admin.trackers.show', compact('tracker'));
    }

    public function destroy(Tracker $tracker)
    {
        abort_if(Gate::denies('tracker_delete'), Response::HTTP_FORBIDDEN, '403 Forbidden');

        $tracker->delete();

        return back();
    }

    public function massDestroy(MassDestroyTrackerRequest $request)
    {
        Tracker::whereIn('id', request('ids'))->delete();

        return response(null, Response::HTTP_NO_CONTENT);
    }
}
```

As you can my HomeController is to long
I only want to get data of tracker which is assign to a user .

How can i do that I`ve done so much research and im fighting for this for 2 months
But i cant find the answer on google ...

I really apreciate your help thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

In the home controller, you are repeating yourself so many times with the same code which violates the **DRY** principle.

First of all, you can create two private methods in the controller one for sum and one for delete.

```
   public function index() 
{

// actually you need not to do everytime the query. Just pass parameters as required. 

         $Admin = $this->addSlp($name= 'Admin')-$this->deleteSlp($name= 'Admin');
         
    }
```

private function for add slp and you may use wherehas and other cconditions here as required.

```
private function addSlp($name)
{
  return Tracker::where('name', '=', $name)->sum('add_slp');
}
```

private function for delete slp

```
private function deleteSlp($name)
{
  return Tracker::where('name', '=', $name)->sum('delete_slp');
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment @Dip Ghosh
Im new at laravel and its hard for me to understand whats going on in that code .
Ive tried putting private function as what you write above and also added public function under the private function on the same controller 
It returns me

 SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'name' in 'where clause' (SQL: select sum(`add_slp`) as aggregate from `trackers` where `name` = Admin and `trackers`.`deleted_at` is null)